# Encountering ENOENT in node.js

Tags: node.js, process, child-process

I have an obscure error, ENOENT, that I'm encountering. Here's the output.

```
converting SVG to a PNG

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
```

Here's the code. Examining the print statements, it seems to be happening right before the call to `child.spawn`.

```
child = require 'child_process'

svgToPNG = (svg, reply, log) ->
  # set up a child process to call convert svg: png:-
  log "converting SVG to a PNG"
  convert = child.spawn 'convert', ['svg:', 'png:-']
  convert.stderr.on 'data', (data) ->
    log data.toString()
    convert.stdout.end data
    return reply "error occurred"
  # create buffer that output will be piped into
  res = ""
  # pipe this process' stdout into res
  convert.stdout.pipe res
  # pipe svg into the process and close its input, startin the process
  convert.stdin.end svg
  # call reply with the res as content
  log "OK done converting to a PNG, replying"
  reply res
```

Calling `convert` from the command line works just fine. I'm not sure why this is failing.

Answer (score 0):

When you type `convert` in a shell, the shell locates the full path to the `convert` executable by searching directories in the `PATH` environment variable. `child_process.spawn` doesn't do that. So either use an absolute path to `convert` or use the `/usr/bin/env` program , which will search the PATH like the interactive shell does. If you use `/usr/bin/env`, that becomes your command, `convert` becomes argument 1, and the rest of convert's arguments follow that.